# ui-grid not showing data angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, ui-grid

Can someone please help me. I want to implement data display using ui-grid. But the grid is not displaying data just showing blank yet when i use table with `<tr ng-repeat="transaction in savingaccountdetails.transactions>` data is displayed.

I want to use ui-grid because of the ability to have fixed header while scrolling for large data but its so hard to make table header fixed, most times columns don't align. i tried most cases but not working as expected.

My codes are as below:-

```
var columnsUiGrid = [
                { displayName: 'Value Date', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.date'},
                { displayName: 'Seq', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.id'},
                { displayName: 'Number', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.transactionCode'},
                { displayName: 'Type', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.transactionCode'},
                { displayName: 'Debit', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.amount'},
                { displayName: 'Credit', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.amount'},
                { displayName: 'Balance', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.runningBalance'},
                { displayName: 'Tlr#', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.teller'},
                { displayName: 'Reference', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.referenceCode'},
                { displayName: 'Description', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.description'}
            ];
            scope.gridOptions = {
                columnDefs: columnsUiGrid,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                enableRowHeaderSelection : false,
                multiSelect: false,
                data: 'accountdetails'
            };

resourceFactory.savingsResource.get({accountId: routeParams.id, associations: 'all'}, function (data) {
                scope.accountdetails = data;
            });
```

From the above i get the following errors from web browser console:-
When i use with the quotes i.e 'accountdetails' i get the error below:-

```
angular.js:9400 TypeError: d.$applyAsync is not a function
    at h (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:7:2757)
    at post (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:7:4152)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6602:44
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6224:13)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6414:13
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7559:11
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10930:81)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11016:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11936:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11762:31) <div ui-i18n="en" class="influxGrid ui-grid ng-isolate-scope grid1505208757076" id="transactionGrid" ui-grid-selection="" ui-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 340px;">
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9400
(anonymous) @ angular.js:6836
nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:6227
(anonymous) @ angular.js:6414
(anonymous) @ angular.js:7559
wrappedCallback @ angular.js:10930
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11016
$eval @ angular.js:11936
$digest @ angular.js:11762
$apply @ angular.js:12042
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13575
completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:4109
(anonymous) @ angular.js:4416
angular.js:9400 TypeError: b.forEach is not a function
    at p.modifyRows (ui-grid.min.js:7)
    at ui-grid.min.js:7
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:10930)
    at angular.js:11016
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:11936)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:11762)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12042)
    at angular.js:13575
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4109)
    at angular.js:4416
```

Comment: You should remove single quote from the gridOptions data for 'accountdetails' to accountdetails (without single quotes).

Comment: Can you have a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExKbYUeh3KBwpB8Q2cHW?p=preview) for a sample binding example of ui-grid?

Comment: I've looked at you plunker and I think you some service issue over there. Since I've made the sample out of your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHDaydAVhYwbpvGIEdGE?p=preview). Please have a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHDaydAVhYwbpvGIEdGE?p=preview).

Comment: I've made a tweak on the code to have WDL, DEP on your code with this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/CRS4KBlLTDJuUcnjp96n?p=preview). Check it out this new [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CRS4KBlLTDJuUcnjp96n?p=preview) @IppezRobert

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS, thanks so much it works as expected but now there are some transactions which are reversed, so i would like to strike through the row with reversed transaction and text color should be red. And i have a similar challenge for loans as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235603/creating-table-logic-formatting with the ui-grid format here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KweVC.png

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS plunk for loans is here http://plnkr.co/edit/NmBQs5gV2mVYKaevckdd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you are using the scope as "scope" and not like "$scope". I couldn't say where your problem is but maybe if you try your code this way:

```
var columnsUiGrid = [
            { displayName: 'Value Date', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.date'},
            { displayName: 'Seq', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.id'},
            { displayName: 'Number', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.transactionCode'},
            { displayName: 'Type', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.transactionCode'},
            { displayName: 'Debit', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.amount'},
            { displayName: 'Credit', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.amount'},
            { displayName: 'Balance', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.runningBalance'},
            { displayName: 'Tlr#', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.teller'},
            { displayName: 'Reference', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.referenceCode'},
            { displayName: 'Description', field: 'accountdetails.transactions.description'}
        ];
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnsUiGrid,
            enableSorting: false,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableRowHeaderSelection : false,
            multiSelect: false,
            data: $scope.accountdetails
        };
resourceFactory.savingsResource.get({accountId: routeParams.id, associations: 'all'}, function (data) {
                $scope.accountdetails = data;
            });
```

Please let us know more details about your problem

Comment: I have created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/S99UlC8ExQKUUGfChVOO?p=preview please help me.

Comment: with the above plunker, i get the error : `angular.js:9400 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (ui-grid.min.js:7)
    at invoke (angular.js:3708)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3719)
    at angular.js:6770
    at angular.js:6183
    at forEach (angular.js:310)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6170)
    at angular.js:6414
    at angular.js:7559
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:10930)`